# PhpStorm - li [TAB] autocompletes with "link" element instead of "li" element

Tags: autocomplete, ide, phpstorm

In PhpStorm, when I type `li` and press `tab`, it auto-completes with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="" >` I want it to auto-complete with `<li></li>` instead.

However, looking at the settings, this is what it should already be doing...

in the "Live Template" settings, it looks like this:

[image]

So according to these settings, `li` should autocomplete to `<li>...</li>`, and `link` should auto complete to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="...">`. Which would be great. But the `li` live template never works, it seems to be giving priority to the `link` live template.

How can I get the `li` live template to work, without disabling the `link` live templates?

Update:

Here's a gif of what happens in a blank "blade" scratch:

[image]

I also discovered that this only happens in Laravel `blade` files. When I tried it in an HTML scratch note, it works (a `li` element was auto-completed)

If I disable the live templates in zen-html for "link", then it also works (but I'd rather not disable them)

Other details:

- PhpStorm 2019.3.4
- 66 "bundled" plugins (I haven't changed these from default settings)
- downloaded plugins: .env files support, BrowseWordAtCaret, Laravel, Solarized Themes

Comment: 1) Can you make a small video/gif/screencast to show what exactly happens on a screen (code completion popup if it's visible) just before you will be hitting a `Tab`? 2) What is the context (what file type; where exactly you are typing this etc). 3) Any JS related plugins/context here?  P.S. It works just fine for me in 2019.3.4 if I jut type `li[TAB]` in plain HTML context with no code completion visible.

Comment: +1 to the above comment - works perfectly fine for me. Video recording of your steps plus the information about the context you try to expand the template in (file type, etc.) would be helpful

Comment: ok, I've added additional details. Apparently, it works fine in pure HTML contexts, but not in "blade" contexts. @LazyOne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your gif the code completion popup has different Live Template entry selected when you hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

If you close the completion popup before that (with <kbd>Esc</kbd>) it will expand into `<li></li>` as expected.

---

In any case, this looks related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-50106. Ticket says it's fixed for next major version (2020.1)

Please try 2020.1 Beta / EAP build to see if this will work for you: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/nextversion/

Comment: I guess I should have checked for a bug first... but I don't think I would have found this one since it doesn't mention `li` elements. Anyway, that bug sounds like exactly what I'm experiencing, so good to hear it's fixed now, thanks. :D